# Payment Gateway integration for master and visa card in opencart

Tags: e-commerce

Hello I am new to opencart just installed it I am wondering how can i add visa and master card support in my payment method please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom payment module and a contract with your bank or another provider.

for guidelines look here: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=136&t=30653

if you are looking for a simple way, OC has a module for paypal and paypal supports virtually all credit cards.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am in pakistan. we don't have a privilege to use paypal service for somereason, is this solution is valid in this case.

Comment: thats sad... Well in this case, have a look at the link I provided,  it is quite straight forward to setup a payment module if you know your way around OC and PHP.

Comment: @SalmanAhmed, by the way, if you like my answer dont forget to accept it.